# Contraseña inicio sesión Stack Overflow

Tags: soporte, cuentas-de-usuario, login

Estoy buscando algun apartado que permita cambiar la contraseña de inicio de sesion en mi cuenta de Stack Overflow pero no lo encuentro. ¿Podrias indicarme donde encontrarlo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ve a

1. Perfil
2. Editar perfil y configuración
3. Mis inicios de sesión
4. cambiar contraseña

[image]